# Is there a way to make Fruit Ninja app run for an unlimited amount of time on an Android device?

Tags: android

I am taking some bandwidth and frequency measurements while running Fruit Ninja app on an Android device. (This is part of a use case testing process.) I created a script that automatically gets the CPU frequency data. The script changes the actual CPU frequency every 30 seconds (just enough to get a stable frequency data), to a number in this long list of CPU frequencies: cpufreq=( 51000 102000 204000 306000 ... many more! ). The problem is that Fruit Ninja runs for only 60 seconds, so I can take only 2 measurements during one run, and then I have to manually select "Retry" on the screen. This is too time-consuming. I would like a way to make Fruit Ninja to run for an unlimited time without human interaction, or a way to automatically do "Retry", so that I can just run the script and wait for the results. (I do have a way to automatically start the fruit ninja app from the home screen, this is not I want, because after the app starts user still needs to select "start" or "retry", which I don't know how to simulate.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be easier to find a similarly taxing game without the time limit. Does it *have* to be Fruit Ninja?

Comment: I was given three games on different CPU and GPU intensive levels, but I think you are right, it makes sense to find a game with similar CPU intensity that can run for a long time. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

You should give [monkeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) a try.

Comment: We tried monkeyrunner before, the problem is that the program puts non-negligible burden on the processor, and we want very accurate bandwidth and frequency data. So it might not fit in our performance sensitive testing scheme. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

The design of the Android platform will prevent this, unless you somehow gain access to the source of Fruit Ninja.

In Android, each application is an "island," untouchable by any other application, unless it is explicitly allowed by both applications. Interacting with an application in such a way is forbidden by the Android ecosystem, by design. It is a security thing.